# Autotype abbreviations

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity

I've been using AutoHotkey for Windows to have some handy scripts, e.g. auto type some templates: ttyl => thanks, talk to you later

Is there any app for Ubuntu to expand abbreviations like this way in any application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)

Recently recommended by [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5845445/the-best-text-expansion-app-for-linux)

It uses python on the backend and works across applications.

Also of mention is [Snippits](http://lifehacker.com/351285/automate-repetitive-typing-with-snippits) but it doesn't come with easy installing instructions.